# Array list with 2 values and doing it to a top 10 list

Tags: node.js, discord.js

im working on a Discord bot and have a reputation system with fs (npm package) and saving peoples reps in a file and doing the file name as they discord id

now im working on a top 10 command and would need some help here, i currently have this as code:

```
 let users = [];
 let reps = [];
 fs.readdirSync('./data/reps/').forEach(obj => {
   users.push(obj.replace('.json', ''))
   let file = fs.readFileSync(`./data/reps/${obj}`)
   let data = JSON.parse(file)
   reps.push(data.reps)
 })
 let top = [...users, ...reps]
 top.sort((a,b) => {a - b})
 console.log(top)
```

the files form the users are like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        "437762415275278337"
    ],
    "reps": 1
}
```

users are the current users that can't rep the persion anymore and don't need to use it in the command

i wan to get the top 10 of reps so that i can get the user id and how many reps they have, how could i do it with the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
const topTen = fs.readdirSync('./data/reps/').map(obj => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(`./data/reps/${obj}`);
    const data = JSON.parse(file);

    return { ...data, name: obj.replace('.json', '') };
 }).sort((a, b) => a.reps - b.reps).slice(0, 10);

 console.log(topTen);
```

Comment: this only shows me people that have only 1 rep and not the people with like 30 reps because they are at the bottom of the list and i still need the file name to get wich member it is

Comment: To reverse the order just change `a.reps - b.reps` with `b.reps - a.reps`; while about the file name I'm not clear what you need, I simply added it to the object as you did in your example.

Comment: the filenames are the users id that has ... reps and would need the filename to identify the user that has ... reps

Comment: ok i already got it, didn't saw that the name is the id from the user, but thansk for the help! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would change how you push the data

```js
const users = [];
fs.readdirSync('./data/reps/').forEach(obj => {
   let file = fs.readFileSync(`./data/reps/${obj}`)
   let data = JSON.parse(file)
   reps.push({ reps: data.reps, id: obj.replace(".json", "") });
})
```

That way when you sort the array the id goes along with

```js
//define this after the fs.readdirSync.forEach method
const top = users.sort((a,b)=> a.reps-b.reps).slice(0,10);
```

If you want an array of top ids

```js
const topIds = top.map(e => e.id);
```

If you want a quick string of it:

```js
const str = top.map(e => `${e.id}: ${e.reps}`).join("\n");
```

Also you should probably just have one or two json files, one would be the array of user id's and their reps and then the other could be of user id's and who they can't rep anymore

Comment: "/define this after the fs.readdirSync.forEach method
const top = users.sort((a,b)=> a-b).slice(0,10);"

This will sort the user ids and not the reps i wanted, its like first persion has 9 2nd 2 3nd 3 4th 1

Comment: it would fail in sorting since you are subtracting objects, i meant `a.reps - b.reps`. You already accepted the other answer which was just pretty much my answer with less info, but I'll keep it up incase you wanted the other arrays.